# Disable the Service for 3 hours in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, alarmmanager

How to disable the android service for few hours and restart it again ?

```
daybtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//hide for 2 hr
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(c, "Service disabled for 5min", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Service.class);
    context.stopService(i);


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run () {
            // Do delayed stuff!
             Intent intent2 = new Intent(c, Service.class);
                c.startService(intent2);
        }
    }, 300000L); //5 min delay 
}
});
```

The above code works for 5 min, but if i try to execute the same for 1hr or more(3600000L) then its not working. How can i achieve this for more than an hour or 2 ?.  Thank you

Comment: You may have better luck with [alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html).

Comment: Defnitely use `AlarmManager` for this. Android will not keep your process running for 1 hour if the user isn't using it. Therefore your process will get killed due to lack of use and your `Runnable` will never get run.

Comment: Thank you Kevin and David, will try to implement using AlarmManager